# "Package 'linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic' has no installation candidate"

Tags: apt, linux-kernel

I'm trying to resolve an issue that [I posted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554624/how-to-resolve-the-lib-modules-3-13-0-27-generic-build-no-such-file-or-direct). I'm basically trying to successfully run [this script](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/acpi-stuff/blob/master/acpi_dump_info/Makefile). To do that, I believe (and I its very possible that I'm wrong) I need to install the `linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic` package. But the installation command is always failing

```
mg@MG-7520SE:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic' has no installation candidate
```

Searching using `apt-cache search` doesn't return a valid result because none of the returned results match the version I need, which is `3.13.0-27`

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
linux-headers-3.16.0-23 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-23-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-generic - Generic Linux kernel headers
linux-headers-lowlatency - lowlatency Linux kernel headers
linux-headers-virtual - Transitional package.
linux-libc-dev - Linux Kernel Headers for development
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-source-3.16.0 - Linux kernel source for version 3.16.0 with Ubuntu patches
linux-virtual - Minimal Generic Linux kernel and headers
linux-headers-3.4.0-4-goldfish - Linux kernel headers for version 3.4.0 on Android touch emulation
linux-headers-goldfish - Linux kernel headers for the goldfish kernel.
linux-headers-3.16.0-24 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-24-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-24-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-25 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-25-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

My system information

```
mg@MG-7520SE:~$ uname -a
Linux MG-7520SE 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mg@MG-7520SE:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, from the `apt-cache search linux-headers` the cause should be obvious:

Simply stated, the package isn't available in Ubuntu 14.10. You should instead install `linux-headers-3.16.0-24`, `linux-headers-3.16.0-25` or save yourself from all problems and use `linux-headers-generic` which is a meta-package that depends on the latest available kernels (going by your other question in Ask Ubuntu, you seem to be using 14.10 with the kernel of 14.04, which is a big no-no, install also the `linux-image-generic` package, or better yet, `linux-generic` which assures you to have the latest available kernel-header pair
, and restart the system).

Comment: Attempting to install `linux-headers-3.16.0-25` fails because `apt-get` reports that I already have this package installed. I don't understand, how is that possible if running `uname -r` returns `3.13.0-27-generic` !

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana that it's already explained in my answer. You simply didn't upgrade your kernel along with your system.

Comment: I tried installing `` and `` but they both were already installed. But attempting to install `` worked. I'm installing it now. Is this a %100 safe operation ? To upgrade the kernel whenever possible ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana normally, yes, you want to run the latest available kernel and in this case you want to run the kernel with the latest drivers to make sure your bug is properly reported.

Comment: Solved. And fixed my brightness buttons too ! This gave me hope to try my discrete graphics card as well. I'll try enabling ASAP. Thanks a lot.